# make a page contnt to apear in a (contntPlaceHolder) asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, hyperlink

I use visual studio to create a website using ASP.net +C#

I ve created a page called SitesGuide
I want to make a simple navigation in the sidebar on the Right
so as u see in the picture in the link below 4 hyper links

https://twitter.com/MetfalaDoamz/status/465026709721346048

when I press general the (general page content appears in the content place holder on the left of SitesGuide page) how to do that ?
and the same for all the hyperlinks

in Html pages I used the frame but now it is not working

this is my master page source code

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <title>Manuscripts</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function mainmenu() {
            $(" #nav ul ").css({ display: "none" }); //Opera Fix
            $(" #nav li").hover(function () {
                $(this).find('ul:first').css({ visibility: "visible", display: "none" }).show(400);
            }
            , function () {
                $(this).find('ul:first').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            mainmenu();
        });



    </script>
    <link href="CSS/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="banner">

            </div>
            <div id="navigation">
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li><a href="Home.aspx" runat="server">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" runat="server">MANUSCRIPTS</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" runat="server">Terms</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" runat="server">Gallery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="References.aspx" runat="server">References</a></li>
                            <li><a href="SitesGuide.aspx" runat="server">Sites guide</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" runat="server">WAQFS</a>
                    <li><a href="#" runat="server">Project</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="Wagf.aspx" runat="server">Waqfs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="ManuscriptS.aspx">Manuscripts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                        <li><a href="Waqf_Overview.aspx" runat="server">Management</a></li>


                </ul>
                <div id="Login" align="right">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblLogin" runat="server" ForeColor="Brown" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" ForeColor="Brown" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="content_area">

                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

            </div>

            <div id="sidebar">

                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

            </div>

            <div id="footer">
                <p>All Rights reserved.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my SitesGuide.aspxsource code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SitesGuide.aspx.cs" Inherits="SitesGuide" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">


   </p>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="ContentPlaceHolder2">

</asp:Content
```

>

Comment: we will need much more information in order to be able to help you. add some cs and aspx code and try to describe your problem in a few more sentences

Comment: Sorry Ive edited the question